# Linq select between 2 values for a list of id

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq query that works in the singular - here it is:

```
public static AmountRange GetAmountRange(int term)
{
     return amountTable
        .Where(x => term.IsBetween(x.MinTerm, x.MaxTerm))
        .Select(x => new AmountRange(term, x.MinAmount, x.MaxAmount))
        .First();
}
```

The IsBetween function is a simple 'int' extension method, which does exactly what it says.

What I would like to do is to make another variant that accepts an array of 'int[]' as the initial param so that I'm not calling the query several times.

If this was an array of single values, I would simply use the .Contains functionality, but it doesn't.

Here's an example that uses .Contains - however, it doesn't allow for a range - only a single value. It needs to be converted so thateach term IsBetween MinAmount and MaxAmount.

```
public static IEnumerable<AmountRange> SelectAmountRange(int[] terms)
{
    var termList = terms.ToList();

    return amountTable.Where(t => termList.Contains(t.MinAmount))
        .Select(x => new AmountRange(term would go here, x.MinAmount, x.MaxAmount))
        .ToList();
}
```

So, in a nutshell, I want to achieve the following:

- Pass an array of int[] (terms) as the parameters.
- Select all rows where each term value falls between the table values
  MinAmount and Max Amount.

Comment: I think you are backwards.  Change function to return List<AmountRange>.  Then change .First() to .List().

Comment: @jdweng - the example bove is what exists curently for a single param - it it not a work in progress for the new version.

Comment: why are you returning `First` and not `ToList`? if this is algorithm that you are 100% sure it works correct, then I have no argument. I'm just asking so I can provide correct answer.

Comment: please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you are asking to return single `AmountRange` for `int[]` as input. but in your second example you are returning multiple items. whats the logic here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public static AmountRange GetAmountRange(int[] terms)
{
     return amountTable
        .Where(x => terms.All(y => y.IsBetween(x.MinTerm, x.MaxTerm)))
        .Select(x => new AmountRange(terms, x.MinAmount, x.MaxAmount))
        .ToList();
}
```

Another approach

```
public static List<AmountRange> GetAmountRange(int[] terms)
{
     return amountTable
        .Select(x => new {Item=x, Terms=terms.Where(z => z.IsBetween(x.MinTerm, x.MaxTerm))})
        .SelectMany(x => x.Terms.Select(term => new AmountRange(term, x.Item.MinAmount, x.Item.MaxAmount)))
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: this should return `List<AmountRange>` not `AmountRange`

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary - I think you have the wrong idea, the first example was just an example of how it is done as a single row.

Comment: if you return single item for single input then i assume you should return multiple items for multiple inputs. if that's not the case here, then your question is not clear. please explain further. in your second example you are returning multiple items too. @JohnOhara

Comment: @detoix - this looks good but I need to return the term too - see the class AmountRange - the variable terms needs to be the single term, not the list.

Comment: @ODawgG - just highlighted this detoix - you're right it should be the individual term being queried.

Comment: How do you krow which term should be passed to constructor if multiple are vaild?

Comment: Sorry deleted my comment by mistake. So yah, terms should not be passed to the object AmountRange as an array.

Comment: Each term is in the 'terms' array - when the IsBetween query is carried out the value 'term' should be preserved so that it can be projected into AmountRange.

Comment: Posted another idea - syntax may be broken; written on cell phone

Comment: Yes, syntax is broken - I just can't work out where.

Comment: Try now - hopefully fixed

Comment: Thanks for your effort - going off to test answers now and will award as soon as.

Answer (score 1):

Given the object:

```
public class AmountRange
{
    public AmountRange(int term, int minAmount, int maxAmount)
    {
        Term = term;
        MinTerm = minAmount;
        MaxTerm = maxAmount;
    }

    public int Term { get; }
    public int MinTerm { get; }
    public int MaxTerm { get; }
}
```

I think what you're looking for then is a join on passed terms and the terms in the object and then applying the filter accordingly:

```
    public static IEnumerable<AmountRange> GetAmountRange(int[] terms)
    {
        return amountTable
            .Join(terms, 
                range => range.Term, 
                term => term, 
                (range, term) => new { range, term })
           .Where(x => x.term.IsBetween(x.range.MinTerm, x.range.MaxTerm))
           .Select(x => new AmountRange(x.term, x.range.MinTerm, x.range.MaxTerm));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort - going off to test answers now and will award as soon as.

Answer (score 0):

> What I would like to do is to make another variant that accepts an array of 'int[]' as the initial param so that I'm not calling the query several times.

You can use a dictionary of `int` to `AmountRange`. That is, each distinct `int` is mapped to a single `AmountRange`.

```
public static Dictionary<int, AmountRange> GetAmountRanges(int[] terms)
{
     return terms.Distinct().ToDictionary(
                 key => key,  
                 term => amountTable
                 .Where(x => term.IsBetween(x.MinTerm, x.MaxTerm))
                 .Select(x => new AmountRange(term, x.MinAmount, x.MaxAmount))
                 .First());
}
```

in order to access dictionary items.

```
var ranges = GetAmountRanges(terms);

foreach(var kvp in ranges)
{
    var index = kvp.Key;
    var range = kvp.Value;

    // do stuff
}
```

If `terms` can contain duplicates, then you should access items in this way.

```
var ranges = GetAmountRanges(terms);

foreach(var i in terms)
{
    var kvp = ranges[i];
    var index = kvp.Key;
    var range = kvp.Value;

    // do stuff
}
```